# Асинхронная обработка данных в Yii2

Tags: yii2

Как работать с методами pull и push?

Асинхронная обработка данных #

Когда запрос включает в себя некоторые ресурсоемкие операции, вы должны подумать о том, чтобы выполнить эти операции асинхронно, не заставляя пользователя ожидать их окончания.

Существует два метода асинхронной обработки данных: pull и push.

В методе pull, всякий раз, когда запрос включает в себя некоторые сложные операции, вы создаете задачу и сохраняете ее в постоянном хранилище, таком как база данных. Затем в отдельном процессе (таком как задание cron) получаете эту задачу и обрабатываете ее.

Этот метод легко реализовать, но у него есть некоторые недостатки. Например, задачи надо периодически забирать из места их хранения. Если делать это слишком редко, задачи будут обрабатываться с большой задержкой, а если слишком часто - это будет создавать большие накладные расходы.

В методе push, вы можете использовать очереди сообщений (например, RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, Amazon SQS, и т.д.) для управления задачами. Всякий раз, когда новая задача попадает в очередь, это инициирует обработку этой задачи обработчиком.

Answer (score 2):

В оригинале заголовок - "Processing Data Offline", мне кажется перевод не совсем корректным. Не утверждаю, но предположу, что pull и push это не существующие методы в фреймрорке, это скорее название подхода к реализации, общепринятые название методов реализации. А уже саму реализацию вы делаете сами.

Вы можете выбрать подход push - установить расширение для RabbitMQ, и по документации от расширения, уже работать с очередью.

Вы можете выбрать подход pull - реализовать свою очередь, где то эту очередь хранить, и с помощью некого инструмента периодически забирать из очереди данные и обработать их.

P.S. все буквы, личное мнение и может не совпадать с мыслями изложеными в документации.